# Selecting rows between two dates in SQL with PHP

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to get rows from my database between two dates. I've used other questions here to get to this point, but I don't know how to move forward from here.

Here is the code, and underneath are the screenshots of the output and a photo running the query in SQL.

Thanks for the help in advance!

--

This first section of code outputs the ID, name, etc.

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM songs ";
$result = $link->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["ID"] . " - Name: " . $row["name"] . " " . $row["released"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

/* close connection */    

$link->close();

?>
```

This section of code outputs "0 Results"

```
<?php

$from_date = '2015-01-01';
$to_date = '2017-04-04';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM songs WHERE released BETWEEN '" . $from_date .  "' AND '" . $to_date . "' ";
$result = $link->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["ID"] . " - Name: " . $row["name"] . " " . $row["released"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

/* close connection */    

$link->close();

?>
```

[This is what the page looks like with the above code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONcIN.png)

[I've successfully selected the rows in SQL.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41xDr.png)

**EDIT:** I made a mistake when writing the code into the question for the IF ELSE statement on the 2nd block of code. I just updated it to what I actually have on the site. I didn't change anything based on the solutions, and am still not getting the rows to print.

Comment: `while () {} else {}` isn't valid in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah man, I just needed to had to comment out this line from the first block:

```
$link->close();
```

I apologize to everyone who answered if it wasn't clear that the blocks of code followed one another. Anyways, for anyone else with the same problem, don't close the connection -_-

[Here's what is output when I comment out the line from the first block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YkCO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your results are listed - as you can see from your screenshot. Problem: `While` along with `else` does not make sence.

your last example is missing a `}` so it says: `while { } else { echo "0 results"}`

But the `echo "0 results"` should be related to the `num_rows`-check, not to the `while`.

Comment: `while() {} else {}` isn't valid. There is no missing `}`. It's just a nesting issue.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the replies. I made a mistake pasting my code for this question. It's updated the second section now to what I actually have on the site. 

The else statement should now be associated with the if statement, and I am still outputting "0 Results"

Answer (score 0):

You done everything right, except using `while/else` ;
Your code (2-nd) section should look like this:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  while () {
     //print your rows
  }
} else {

  //Say that there's 0 results
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I made a mistake pasting my code for this question. It's updated now to what I actually have on the site. I just tried the code you posted and am still outputting "0 Results".